# Quiz for Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a bag with three standard 6-sided dice with face values [1,2,3,4,5,6] and two non-standard 6-sided dice with face values [2,3,3,4,4,5]. Someone draws a die from the bag, rolls it, and announces it was a 3. What is the probability that the die that was rolled was a standard die?

Input your answer as a fraction or as a decimal with at least three digits of precision.

Comment: Before your question gets closed for lack of context, you should do more than simply copy the question from the source.  What are you studying?  Is this a course, or self-study?  What specific techniques are you studying at the moment that might be brought to bear on this problem?

Comment: **Observation:** $~$ There are *seven* faces of `3` that could be shown and all faces are equally likely to be shown. $~$ So when given that a face of `3` is shown the probability that it is on one from the three standard dice is....

Comment: P(Standard Dice=(3/5)
P(Non Standard Dice=(2/5)
P(Standard Dice | 3) = (1/3)
P(Non Standard Dice | 3) = (2/3)

P(3| Standard Dice) = (3/5)*(1/6)/((3/5)*(1/6)+(2/5)*(2/6)) = 0.42857142857

Answer (score 2):

Setup and major hints:

Let $A$ represent the event that a standard die was selected.  $A^c$ then represents the event that a non-standard die was selected.

Let $B$ represent the event that the die that was rolled shows a $3$.

The problem asks you to find $Pr(A\mid B)$

Bayes' Theorem implies

$$Pr(A\mid B)=\dfrac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$$

The law of total probability implies that $Pr(B)=Pr(B\cap A)+Pr(B\cap A^c)$.

You were told enough information from the problem statement to start filling in specific probabilities and continue towards an answer.

(*This setup is almost identical for most introductory questions related to Bayes' Theorem*)